# I need to close Popup in click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

here is my fiddle

> http://jsfiddle.net/Raghava0330/6f9ge64f/

```
 . In this fiddle after clicking Login Button, Popup should be closed. Thanks in advance
```

Comment: And what problem did you encounter when you tried to add this functionality yourself?

Comment: I didn't get any problem but after clicking that Login button Popup should be closed .

Comment: Why did you not posted your code here. Have you seen the warning message? __Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.__

Comment: It seems to work properly. So vague question I am really wondering why it has only one downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your jQuery code:

```
$("#login_btn").click(function(){
    $(".popup").close();
});
```

The login_btn is the button inside the popup window.

Comment: Did you gave the button the id=login_btn?

Comment: Its true that it doesnt work. You call the popup window with CSS. Thats not bad, but it is better to call it from jQuery just to keep things clear. I will look it and post something from scratch.